# Chess engine with an ELO of less than 1800

Tags: engines, software, rating, elo, uci

I am looking for an UCI compatible engine with an ELO of less than 1800. Not a version of Houdini or Stockfish with an ELO of 1800. I want a engine with a real ELO rating of 1800 or less. If you can help me with links, that would be great.

Comment: You may want to have a look here: http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/404/ and here: http://www.computerchess.org.uk/ccrl/4040/ On the 40 moves in 40 minutes list there is only one engine with an Elo of less than 1800: Ziggurat 0.18 64-bit, with an Elo of 1786. (But I'm not totally sure these Elo ratings can be accurately compared to human FIDE Elo ratings.)

Comment: There is also the famous program Chess Titans, which has a rating of around 1700 Elo on level 10. (Chess Titans is included in Windows Vista and Windows 7, but not in Windows 8.)

Comment: Chess Titans is handicapped, I think. It has several times exchanged a queen for a rook for almost no advantage.

Comment: Really? On level 10? I played a lot of games against it and it never made such blunders on level 10.

Comment: Well, it has happened only once to me. I won that game, but maybe I might have had a checkmate I hadn't noticed or something.

Comment: Gnuchess 5.07 is about 2050 elo

Comment: Is there a basis for your assessment?

Comment: -1: No way. GNUChess is a direct fork of the Fruit chess engine. Fruit has about 2500 Human FIDE. Your answer is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [numpty](https://sites.google.com/site/numptychess/). It claims to have a ELO of about 1500-1800. I've played it on FICS before and it usually has a blitz rating of 1900-2100. Note that FICS ratings are usually horribly skewed by all the cheating that happens on there.

Answer (score 2):

Adam Hair has a rating list for weaker engines:

http://adamsccpages.blogspot.com/p/also-rans-rating-list.html

Grizzly and Chenard are UCI, but a lot of the weaker engines tend to be CECP.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, on the CCRL 40/4 there're around 170 engines under 1800, not just a dozen. You can also check this list based on bullet games: http://e4e6.com/ratings.php?id=1001
Most of the engines work properly, especially at long time controls.
Almost all of them are still available on the Internet, just Google them.

Alex

Answer (score 1):

There is an engine called Delfi made by [msb software](http://www.msbsoftware.it/delfi/). It is designed to play at lower ratings but also to play more like a human amateur. It is commercial, not free but I think there is a free version with some limitations.